# Is there any benefit to use JS extension for config files like ESLINT and Stylelint?

Tags: javascript, config, eslint, stylelint

I was wondering is there any downside or positive side when creating eslint or stylelint etc files to add the JS prefix to it.

I have noticed you can do it in multiple ways:

```
a stylelint property in package.json
a .stylelintrc file
a stylelint.config.js file exporting a JS object


.eslintrc
.eslintrc.js
```

Is there any speed benefit or is one better then the other or is it just personal preference?
is one faster or not?

Comment: The benefit would not be speed. Perhaps some of these formats have greater compatibility with certain configs than others..? Also *file exporting a JS object* is more flexible than the others, it'll permit even more dynamic linting rules

Answer (score 1):

Adding an extension makes it easier for editors, like VS Code, to select the correct language for syntax highlighting, autocompletion etc.

- a `.stylelintrc` file can contain JSON, YAML or JavaScript.
- a `.eslintrc` file can contain JSON or YAML.

This ambiguity isn't good, and the reason that extensionless `.eslintrc` files are now deprecated in ESLint.

The difference between `.stylelintrc.js` and `stylelint.config.js` is purely preference, as is `.stylelintrc.json` and using a `stylelint` property in `package.json`.